# Unable to compile almost anything? Linking problems? C++

Tags: c++

I have just started to learn about how C++ works however it seems that any source code I get I can not get to compile. Even when I try to copy the tutorials in their own project I get errors. For example, when I want to follow along with this, http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-1-3 Visual Studio gives me back tons of errors. http://gyazo.com/7131e8d21a8aa5c44c68f3e846da7921 Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I have tried many different OpenGL and DirectX tutorials and none of them seem to work (on several computers). I then tried Code Blocks and got that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I have compiled the same source code given over the website, it is compiling properly.

Comment: You could start by actually providing the errors here. As it is, this question hardly contains enough info to be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some changes in project settings.
Go to project properties->General->Character Set, use the "Use Unicode Character Set" and then compile the project. It will work perfectly.

Comment: Wow, it fixed my problem with that. How was I supposed to know that though? If I had never asked I don't think I would have ever found that out. I will accept your answer once 5 minutes passes (It won't let me accept sooner)